# Exception Handling in Python - mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, exception, mysql-python

I have a 2 pyton programs
1) 'Prog1.py' which deals with a Database - Querying from the database
2) 'Prog2.py' which contains the main run loop as below

```
#importing the database class from Prog1.py (mysql.connector used to in Prog1.py)
from database import Database
...

#main run loop
while(True):
   time.sleep(0.2)
   for loc in data:
         self.datafunc(loc)
         call_func_fromprg1()
         foo()
         bar()
    #not to run these conditions if exception is met
    if expression1:
        then operation1
    if expression1:
        then operation2
    if expression3:
        then operation3
    if expression4:
        then operation4

    var = time()
```

I am trying to create an Error exception at `call_func_fromprg1()` where a function from Prog1.py is called and raises an error
`mysql.connector.errors.InternalError : Deadlock found when try to get lock`
and skip the rest of the while loop and not update time in the end and reloop after 0.2s again as given in the code.

What i require is the best place to write the below clause

```
try:
...
except:
 continue
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a status variable in the prog2.py like below.

```
from database import Database
...

#main run loop
while(True):
   time.sleep(0.2)
   for loc in data:
         self.datafunc(loc)
         status = call_func_fromprg1()
         foo()
         bar()
    #not to run these conditions if exception is met
    if expression1:
        then operation1
    if expression1:
        then operation2
    if expression3:
        then operation3
    if expression4:
        then operation4
    if status:
        var = time()
```

and in the prog1.py create a return True value like below:

```
def function():
    try:
        # your code here
        #
        return True
    except:
        #Exception codes
        return False
```